# Web referrer from Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

We have a web app that has a security setting where it checks the referrer to allow access. We need to open this website from an Oracle Form. Currently we are using the web.show_document command to achieve this. Trouble is that this command doesn't report any referrer and thus the web app is refusing access. Does anyone know of a way to specify a referrer when opening a website from Oracle Forms? Or another command that sets the INB Server's domain as the referrer?

We are using Forms [32 Bit] Version 10.1.2.0.2 and this is an Ellucian Banner 7.2 forms app. The app we are trying to access is Evisions Argos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, and back and forth with the Evisions Support Desk, it appears that it's impossible to use the Check Referrer security in this setup. Oracle Forms 10 only has the web.show_document function to launch websites on the client computer. And this function creates a new http request with no "referer" http header. Argos specifically uses that header to check for the referrer. What we ended up doing was disable this security check.

In Oracle Forms 11g it is possible to use this Argos security feature with the web.javascript_eval_expr built in. This function allows to run a javascript window.open function which actually adds a referer header.

Here's an example of the call:

```
web.javascript_eval_expr('window.open("https://someargosserver/mrr?report=LONGREPORTIDKEYVALUE&param1=some_text&param2=some_other_value", "_blank");');
```